# Row-wise Broadcast of arbitrary function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

I have a matrix of vectors where each row is a vector. I want to take the mean of all the vectors, then calculate the cosine distance between each vector and this mean, returning an array of distances.

```
>>> x = arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]])
>>> m = x.mean(0)
array([4., 5., 6.])
```

The cosine values are as follows

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
cosine([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
0.0253681538029239
>>> cosine([4,5,6], [4,5,6])
0.0
>>> cosine([7,8,9], [4,5,6])
0.001809107314273195
```

Therefore I want to write a function `f` such that

```
>>> f(x, m)
array([0.0253681538029239, 0.0, 0.001809107314273195])
```

(Or the transpose of such an array. It doesn't matter.)

What is the most efficient, most numpythonic way to write `f`? It seems like the trick is to get the proper broadcast over the `cosine` function, but I haven't figured out how to do this. The following doesn't work.

```
>>> from numpy import frompyfunc
>>> f = frompyfunc(cosine, 2, 1)
>>> f(x, m)
array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

(It looks like here numpy is applying `cosine` element-wise instead of row-wise.)

Is there a way to do this without writing a `for`-loop?

---

It looks like this is possible with `apply_along_axis`.

```
>>> from numpy import apply_along_axis
>>> from functools import partial
>>> g = partial(cosine, m)
>>> apply_along_axis(g, 1, x)
array([0.02536815, 0.        , 0.00180911])
```

Is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reshape your mean array to be 2D.

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
>>> cdist(x, m.reshape(1, -1), metric='cosine')
array([[2.53681538e-02],
   [2.22044605e-16],
   [1.80910731e-03]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess the *trick* would be to use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) that works on 2D arrays in a vectorized manner to get us those cosine distances. So, one way would be -

```
In [59]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

In [61]: cdist(x,x.mean(0,keepdims=True),'cosine')
Out[61]: 
array([[2.53681538e-02],
       [2.22044605e-16],
       [1.80910731e-03]])
```

That `keepdims` lets the input to be `2D` and hence makes it compatible with the cdist input requirements.